# learning to use intrinsics -- segm fault using _mm256_sub_ps

Tags: c, vectorization, intel, intrinsics

I am trying to learn how to use intrinsics.
So , my c code is :

```
void Vor(

    const int NbPoints,
    const int height,
    const int width,
    float * X,
    float * Y,
    int   * V,
    int   * const ouVor )
{

    float Xd , Yd;
    float Distance ,initDistance = FLT_MAX;
    int Threshold;

    int x , y; // pixel coordinates
    int i;

    for ( y = 0; y < height; y++ )
    {
        for ( x = 0; x < width; x++ )
        {
            for ( i = 0; i < NbPoints; i++ )
            {
                Xd = X[ i ] - x;
                Yd = Y[ i ] - y;
                Distance = Xd * Xd + Yd * Yd;

                //if this Point is closer , assign proper threshold
                if ( Distance < initDistance )
                {
                    initDistance = Distance;
                    Threshold = V[ i ];
                }

                *( ouVor + ( x + y * width ) ) = Threshold;

            } /* i */
        } /* x */

    } /* y */


}
```

Now , using openMP and intrinsics . I am doing:

```
void Vor(

    const  int  NbOfPoints,
    const  int  height,
    const  int  width,
    float * restrict X,
    float * restrict Y,
    int   * restrict V,
    int   * restrict ouVor )
{


    __m128 Xd , Yd;

    __m128i Threshold;
    int x , y; // pixel coordinates
    float initDistance = FLT_MAX;

    float * TempDistance = (float*) _mm_malloc( NbOfPoints * sizeof(*TempDistance) ,64 );

    __m128 * SIMDTempDistance = (__m128*) TempDistance;
    __m128 * theX = (__m128*) X;
    __m128 * theY = (__m128*) Y;
    __m128i * theV = (__m128i*) V;
    __m128i * theVor = (__m128i*) ouVor;


        #pragma omp parallel for default( none ) shared( X , Y , V , ouVor ,height , width ,NbOfPoints ) private ( x,y,Xd,Yd,TempDistance ,Threshold ) collapse(2)  
    for ( y = 0; y < height; y++ )
    { 
        for ( x = 0; x < width; x++ )
        {

            __m128 Distance = _mm_load_ps( &initDistance );

            for ( int i = 0; i < NbOfPoints; i++ )
            {
                Xd = _m128_sub_ps( theX[ i ] , x );
                Yd = _m128_sub_ps( theY[ i ] , y );
                SIMDTempDistance[ i ] = _m128_add_ps( Xd * Xd , Yd * Yd );

                __m128 theMin = _m128_gmin_ps( SIMDTempDistance , &Distance );

                Distance = theMin;
                Threshold = theV[ i ];

                } /* i */

                //write result
                *( ouVor + x + y * width ) = Threshold;

            } /* x */

        } /* y */


    _mm_free( TempDistance );

}
```

I am receiving some errors like:

```
function "_m128_sub_ps" declared implicitly
Xd = _m128_sub_ps( theX[ i ] , x );

error: a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "__m128"
Xd = _m128_sub_ps( theX[ i ] , x );

a value of type "__m128i" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int"
*( ouVor + x + y * width ) = Threshold
```

( and the same errors for Yd ,theMin ,SIMDTempDistance )

How can I overcome these problems?

Also, I removed the if statement and used _m128_gmin_ps to find the minimum value.Is my implementation correct?

-------------- UPDATE ---------------

After Sourav Ghosh comment , I search about the headers.
I couldn't find anywhere the 128 bit , so I used 256 bit using `#include <immintrin.h>`

After correcting a couple of lines to:

```
__m256 Distance = _mm256_load_ps( &intiDistance );

__m256 theMin = _mm256_min_ps( SIMDTempDistance[ i ] , &Distance );
```

and all function calls to _mm256 instead of _m256 , I am getting only these errors:

```
error: argument of type "int" is incompatible with parameter of type "__m256"
Xd = _mm256_sub_ps( theX[ i ] , x );
Yd = _mm256_sub_ps( theY[ i ] , y );
```

The x and y are integers and used in the loop . I don't know how to overcome this.

-----UPDATE ----------------------

I figured!I am casting ..
I used :

```
__m256i xxIdx = _mm256_set1_epi32( x );
__m256  xIdx  = _mm256_castsi256_ps( xxIdx );
```

Now , my code is:

```
void Vor(

        const  int  NbOfPoints,
        const  int  height,
        const  int  width,
        float * restrict X,
        float * restrict Y,
        int   * restrict V,
        int   * restrict ouVor )
    {



       __m256 Xd , Yd;

       __m256i Threshold;
        int x , y; // pixel coordinates


        float * TempDistance = (float*) _mm_malloc( NbOfPoints * sizeof(*TempDistance) ,64 );

        __m256 * SIMDTempDistance = (__m256*) TempDistance;
        __m256 * theX = (__m256*) X;
        __m256 * theY = (__m256*) Y;
        __m256i * theV = (__m256i*) V;
        __m256i * theVor = (__m256i*) ouVor;


    #pragma omp parallel for default( none ) shared( X , Y , V , ouVor ,height , width ,NbOfPoints ,ouVor ,theX,theY,theV ) private ( x,y,Xd,Yd,TempDistance ,Threshold,SIMDTempDistance ) collapse(2)  

    for ( y = 0; y < height; y++ )
    { 
        for ( x = 0; x < width; x++ )
        {
                float initDistance = FLT_MAX;
                __m256 Distance = _mm256_set1_ps( initDistance );

                for ( int i = 0; i < NbOfPoints; i++ )
                {
                    __m256i xxIdx = _mm256_set1_epi32( x );
                    __m256  xIdx  = _mm256_castsi256_ps( xxIdx );

                    __m256i yyIdx = _mm256_set1_epi32( y );
                    __m256  yIdx  = _mm256_castsi256_ps( yyIdx );

                    Xd = _m256_sub_ps( theX[ i ] , xIdx );
                    Yd = _m256_sub_ps( theY[ i ] , yIdx );
                    SIMDTempDistance[ i ] = _m256_add_ps( Xd * Xd , Yd * Yd );

                    __m256 theMin = _m256_gmin_ps( SIMDTempDistance , Distance );

                    Distance = theMin;
                    Threshold = theV[ i ];

                    } /* i */

                    //write result
                    *( ouVor + x + y * width ) = Threshold;

                } /* x */

            } /* y */


        _mm_free( TempDistance );

    }
```

I compile like:

```
icc -std=c99 -g -openmp -qopt-report=2 -o mycode mycode.c
```

and it is ok.

BUt running the code gives segmentation fault..

In line:

```
Xd = _m256_sub_ps( theX[ i ] , xIdx );
Yd = _m256_sub_ps( theY[ i ] , yIdx );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well , I used:

```
__m256 LX = _mm256_load_ps( &X[ i ] );
__m256 LY = _mm256_load_ps( &Y[ i ] );
```

instead of:

```
Xd = _m256_sub_ps( theX[ i ] , xIdx );
Yd = _m256_sub_ps( theY[ i ] , yIdx );
```

and it' ok!

Answer (score 1):

I think, you're missing some of the required header files containing the forward declaration of `_m128_sub_ps()` function. We can assume that actually `_m128_sub_ps()` function is having a return type of `__m128`, but without a forward declaration in place, compiler is assuming the *default* return type as `int` for the `_m128_sub_ps()` function. That is why, compiler is emitting

> function "_m128_sub_ps" declared implicitly

Then, the `int` return value is being assigned to a variable of type `__m128`, createing the issue.

---

EDIT:

As per the changed code,

```
int x , y; // pixel coordinates
```

should be

```
__m256 x , y; // pixel coordinates
```

as the [signature of `_mm256_sub_ps()`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/524049) requires both arguments to be of type `__m256`

Comment: @George what is the function prototype of `_m128_sub_ps()`? is it in <ia32intrin.h>?

Comment: :I've tried this already but it gives a lot of errors in the lines where the loops are.For example,error: a value of type "int" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "__m256"
                for ( y = 0; y < height; y++ )........error: mixed simd-scalar operation not allowed
                for ( y = 0; y < height; y++ )..........error: expression must have arithmetic or pointer type
                        for ( x = 0; x < width; x++ )

Comment: @George Well, i'm not sure, but you can _get around_ the warnings by using something like `Xd = _mm256_sub_ps( theX[ i ] , (__m256) x );` and all. However, i'm not sure if that is what you want. Please confirm.

Comment: It gives : cast to type "__m256" is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a little muddled with the intrinsic names.

For 128 bit SSE it's just, e.g.:

```
_mm_sub_ps
```

not:

```
_mm128_sub_ps
```

[The confusion probably arises from the fact that with 256 bit AVX it's `_mm256_sub_ps`.]